# Multivariate apply function to compare, pair-wise, a set of files

Tags: r

I have a vector, which contains names of data vectors, named `c("tom.txt", "tim.txt" , "Amy.txt")`. My task is to: build a symmetric matrix that looks like the following at the end.

```
> m
        tom.txt tim.txt amy.txt
tom.txt       0      10       5
tim.txt      10       0       7
amy.txt       5       7       0
```

The entries are obtained by a function called `get.result(vec1, vec2)`, which finds the corresponding data vectors of the 2 text files in the directory and does some operations to them and then returns a value for each position in the matrix. For instance, if I want to get the entry `m["tom.txt", "tim.txt"]`, I need to pass "tom.txt" and "tim.txt" into `get.result("tom.txt", "tim.txt")`. The content of this function is not important.

However, if I want to compute the value for all entries, it will be tedious to keep typing `get.result("tom.txt", "amy.txt"), get.result("tim.txt", "amy.txt")`, especially when I am actually working with 100 different text files.

My question: Is there an efficient way to program this such that I am always comparing one text file against the rest *(never compare against itself)* and at the same time, I can keep track of their positions in the matrix ?

Should I initialise the matrix with all zeros right at the beginning and set the column and row names to be the text files name ? But in this case, I am not sure how to obtain the column names and row names such that I can pass them into `get.result(vec1, vec2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution

```
fn <- c("tom.txt", "tim.txt" , "Amy.txt")

n <- length(fn)

m <- matrix(0, n, n)

rownames(m) <- fn
colnames(m) <- fn

for (i in 1:n) for (j in i:n) if (i!=j) {
  v <- get.result(fn[i], fn[j])
  m[i,j] <- v
  m[j,i] <- v
}

m
```

Comment: He already is taking care of not doing the upper triangle  with the use of `j in i:n`.

Answer (score 1):

`fn = dir(pattern=".txt")` (change the pattern if needed) will give you the text files in your target folder. You could then loop over that list like in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `combn` function gives you distinct combinations of vector elements:

```
combs <-combn( c("tom.txt", "tim.txt" , "Amy.txt") , 2)
#----------------
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] "tom.txt" "tom.txt" "tim.txt"
[2,] "tim.txt" "Amy.txt" "Amy.txt"
```

You can then :  `apply( combs, 2, get.result)`

Comment: Maybe you need to replace `get.result` with `function(x)get.result(x[1],x[2])` inside `apply` call.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your file names are in a vector, say

```
vec <- c("tom.txt", "tim.txt" , "Amy.txt")
```

you can use

```
temp <- outer(seq(vec), seq(vec), Vectorize(function(x,y) if(x>y) get.result(vec[x],vec[y]) else 0 ))
result <- temp + t(temp)
```

Note that this makes sure `get.result()` is called only once for every relevant comparison, i.e., it's not called for equal files, nor is it called for pairs that differ only by order.

The last line creates a symmetric matrix.

EDIT: to get the names, use this:

```
rownames(result) <- colnames(result) <- vec
```